# How to dynamically add items and attributes to HTML with javascript or jQuery referencing items from a csv or json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, csv

*I am trying to make the following bit of code easier to maintain. I am not a web developer so bear with me. I think the following approach is appropriate.*

I would like to dynamically add content and attributes to an html file using either javascript or jQuery. The items could reside in a `.csv` or `.json` (or something else?) file.

---

### Given content like this

```
<div class="filtr-container">

    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 card filtr-item" data-category="cat-1" data-date="2018-02-09">
        <div class="card-inner-border box-shadow">
            <a href="address-1.html">
                <img class="card-img-top rounded-top" src="./images/image-1.jpg" alt="img-2-alt">
            </a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Title-1</h5>
                <p class="card-text card-desc">
                    This is a description for title-1 content.
                </p>
                <a href="address-1.html">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                </a>
                <p class="card-text">
                    <small class="text-muted">Last updated February 2, 2018</small>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 card filtr-item" data-category="cat-2, cat-3" data-date="2018-02-14">
        <div class="card-inner-border box-shadow">
            <a href="address-2.html">
                <img class="card-img-top rounded-top" src="./images/image-2.jpg" alt="img-2-alt">
            </a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Title-2</h5>
                <p class="card-text card-desc">
                    Here is a long description for title-2 content.
                </p>
                <a href="address-2.html">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                </a>
                <p class="card-text">
                    <small class="text-muted">Last updated February 14, 2018</small>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- MANY MORE CARDS / ITEMS ... -->

</div> <!-- End of filtr-container -->
```

### I think we could abstract the details into something like this (.csv)

```
item-id,title,description,categories,address,image,image-alt,update
1,Title-1,This is a description for title-1 content.,cat-1,address-1.html,image-1.jpg,img-1-alt,2018-02-09
2,Title-2,Here is a long description for title-2 content.,"cat-2, cat-2",address-2.html,image-2.jpg,img-2-alt,2018-02-14
```

---

### What's a nice approach of attack for using `javascript` or `jQuery` to add this content from the `.csv` or `.json` file?

A few concerns:

- The headers of the `.csv` **will not match** verbatim (e.g. `<p class="card-desc">` aligns with the `.csv` header of `description`)
- There could be embedded comma-separated items (e.g. item 2 has categories `cat-2, cat-3` so it gets quotes `"` in the `.csv` -- maybe `.json` would better (?) or perhaps its a non-issue)
- If possible can we reuse the `date` item for both `data-date=` and the final piece of text `<small class="text-muted">` which converts the date into `Last updated month-name-long, dd, yyyy` instead of `yyyy-mm-dd`.
- Some attributes are partial references (e.g. the src for an image is just the final part of the path; stated as `image-1.jpg` in the `.csv` *not* `./images/image-jpg`).

---

To hopefully help make this feel less complicated, here's a picture with the highlighted elements that could be "referenced" from the `.csv` file.

[image: Image highlighted referenced elements]

To me this feels like:

1. Read in the .csv file.
2. For each item in the .csv file, append objects to `$(".filtr-container")` with the shell layout...

But I'm lost when it comes to the particulars or if that's an appropriate approach.

Comment: You have not really stated a goal for doing this other than _I am not a web developer so bear with me. I think the following approach is appropriate._  All of this string parsing is potentially costly in terms of processing. The browser is optimized to do this sort of thing for us rather than writing a bunch of code to wretch control from the browser and do it ourselves. If you have the structure, you have the attributes, you have the attribute values, why not just store all that as HTML and allow the browser to do its job?

Comment: @RandyCasburn The point is those `div` elements are currently maintained by hand. So why not store them in `csv` or `json` file. I believe the string processing is limited with the exception of the date field? I am also not exactly sure what you mean by your last statement:  "If you have the structure, you have the attributes, you have the attribute values, why not just store all that as HTML and allow the browser to do its job?" Can you elaborate?

Comment: That is rhetorical: Your concept modifies `div`, `image`, `a`, `p`, `textNode` DOM nodes , so how do you cross reference each line of your CSV to the DOM node it modifies? It should become self evident that there is a lot more to think about. Even the single answer you've received has avoided this very topic by simplifying it down to _"it's a matter of rendering it to the DOM_". Best of luck to you.

Comment: @RandyCasburn -- ah, I see, I should have been more clear. Every `div` element will have the 'shell' same structure (see the picture) at the bottom; all that changes is the highlighted elements sourced from the csv file. The order of rendering in the DOM does not matter, they can simply be rendered in-order they appear in the `.csv` file (there is already a javascript function that will rearrange the "cards" by date upon load).

Comment: OK. I see it now. Then template parsing is for you. If I get a moment I'll work up an easy answer.

Comment: @RandyCasburn yes. I appreciate any insight you can provide. I took a quick peak at VueJS and it looks pretty slick, but probably overkill for something this simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be searching for template parsing. You can find many libraries that will ease this burden. In its simplest form, template parses carry out the steps in the following code. If you don't need the flexibility, power, features, etc. from a template parser library or full framework, you should consider not including the thousands of lines of code if all you want to accomplish is what is shown below.

Since you mentioned both JSON and CSV I've included the code to parse both. I'll leave the AJAX and date formatting magic to you. I don't think I populate the ID either, but this shows that more data than template attributes will work fine.

```js
let template = document.getElementById('card-template').innerHTML;
let container = document.querySelector('.filtr-container');

// Do some ajax magic to get csv file
let csv = `item-id,title,description,categories,address,image,image-alt,update
1,Title-1,This is a description for title-1 content.,cat-1,address-1.html,https://via.placeholder.com/75,img-1-alt,2018-02-09
2,Title-2,Here is a long description for title-2 content.,cat-2 cat-2,address-2.html,https://via.placeholder.com/75,img-2-alt,2018-02-14`;

let csvLines = csv.split("\n");
let csvHeaders = csvLines.shift().split(',');
csvLines.forEach(line => {
  let parsed = template;
  let props = line.split(',');
  props.forEach((prop, idx) => {
    parsed = parsed.replace('{{' + csvHeaders[idx] + '}}', props[idx]);
  });
  container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + parsed;
});

let json = `[{
  "item-id": "1",
  "title": "Title-1",
  "description": "This is a description for title-1 content.",
  "categories": "cat-1",
  "address": "address-1.html",
  "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/75",
  "image-alt": "img-1-alt",
  "update": "2018-02-09"
}, {
  "item-id": "2",
  "title": "Title-2",
  "description": "Here is a long description for title-2 content.",
  "categories": "cat-2 cat-2",
  "address": "address-2.html",
  "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/75",
  "image-alt": "img-2-alt",
  "update": "2018-02-14"
}]`;

let data = JSON.parse(json);
data.forEach(col => {
  let jParsed = template;
  for (prop in col) {
    jParsed = jParsed.replace('{{' + prop + '}}', col[prop]);
  }
  container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + jParsed;
});
```

```html
<div class="filtr-container">

  <script type="template" id="card-template">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 card filtr-item" data-category="{{categories}}" data-date="{{date}}">
      <div class="card-inner-border box-shadow">
        <a href="{{address}}">
          <img class="card-img-top rounded-top" src="{{image}}" alt="{{image-alt}}">
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{title}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text card-desc">
            {{description}}
          </p>
          <a href="{{address}}">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
          </a>
          <p class="card-text">
            <small class="text-muted">Last updated {{update}}</small>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This post might help you [parse your CSV document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data). If your data lives in a JSON, you can use [JSON.parse](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)

Once you properly retrieved and parsed your data, it's a matter or rendering it to the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction).

You can do it using the standard javascript library, JQuery or frameworks such as React or VueJS